# Only numbers as keyboard input for ipad

Tags: ipad

I have to display a number pad as keyboard for a textfield (it can take only numerals) in case of ipad.setting keyboard type as UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad displays numeric keyboard but user can switch back to alphabets.Is there any keyboard for ipad that just displays numbers?

Answer (score 11):

Use the input type "number"

```
<input type="number" />
```

or failing that use a validation pattern which only accepts numbers.

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" />
```

Both of these should bring up the num pad on iPhones and bring up the iPad keyboard with the numbers exposed (amongst the other keys)

Comment: ps input type "number" falls back to plain old text input in lesser browsers and devices.

Comment: I used pattern="[0-9]*", its working Great, Jazakallah, Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You would have to create your own keyboard to accomplish this.

Comment: Is there some other way.I mean we can disable the button that switches to alphabet.I have no idea creating own keyboard

Comment: It is not wise to alter the built-in keyboard, as this would severely decrease your chances of approval by Apple's review team.

Comment: As far as I think, I need to check ascii value for text entered by the user

Comment: The best way to do this is to provide the user with the default numerical keyboard, and then verify that each entered character is a digit. You could use the valueChanged method of the UITextField to check this and remove that character.

Comment: @Swastik: So, did you figure out how to change the default keyboard or create your own keyboard? I'm also in the same situation that I need to customize the default keyboard. Please give me some hint or link to instruction if possible. Thanks!

Comment: I had put  the checks on the character entered by the user.I show them alert if they enter invalid character.On ipad you cannot change keyboard type

Answer (score 1):

You could get calculator app with open source code and use their keypad code, or do what I did. Made my own by coding the buttons you want and displaying them how you want eg in a square like a calculator. By using on click event to update a numeric variable. Eg multiply the last entered integer by 10 and add the new integer supplied by the on click code. Ie press button 2 and var = 2. Press another 2 and the var is multiplied by 10 and new var is added , to give 22 . Etc